Any pitfalls in upgrading a WPF application from .Net 6 to .Net 8?
We're looking to upgrade some large WPF solutions from .Net 6 to 8, and my understanding is that the process should be straightforward (changing the projects' target framework). But are there any considerations/risks/pitfalls to be aware of regarding the many NuGet packages that we reference?
It was (unsurprisingly) a painful experience when we converted the solutions from .Net Framework 4.x to .Net 6 a couple of years ago, but I'm assuming that a move from 6 to 8 should be much simpler. Is there anything to be aware of beforehand though, e.g. the packages' dependencies? Most include .Net Standard in their lists - does this mean they should "just work" in 8? However there are a few packages that only list specific .Net versions, with no mention of Standard, e.g.

What will happen with packages like these - is there a chance that they will continue to work in 8?

Did you try Upgrade Assistant?
